# Row Index where all Columns meet one Criterion

Tags: r

I got this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
    a = c("1", "2", "", "")
    , b = c("1", "", "3", "")
)

  a b
1 1 1
2 2  
3   3
4
```

I want to indentify (and then actually remove) the rows where all columns fulfill one particular criterion - in this case `== ""`

Desired output:

```
  a b
1 1 1
2 2  
3   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a logical matrix by doing the comparison with `==`, get the `rowSums` of the TRUE values, check if it is not equal to number of columns of dataset to subset the rows

```
df[rowSums(df == "") != ncol(df),]
#  a b
#1 1 1
#2 2  
#3   3
```

---

Or another option is `filter_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter_all(any_vars(. != ''))
#   a b
#1 1 1
#2 2  
#3   3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `base R` would be:

```
df[sapply(1: nrow(df), function (i) all(df[i,] == '')) != TRUE, ]

#   a b
# 1 1 1
# 2 2  
# 3   3
```